# Stream file log to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an EC2-instance running docker using docker-compose.
I would like all logs written to a file by one of the applications to send that data async to CloudWatch. It would be ideal to have a separate container that is sharing the logs directory with the application container and runs something like `tail -f` and sends the output to CloudWatch.

I am no expert, but I imagine that Filebeat does something similar, but Don't know if I can configure it to send to CloudWatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up using [this docker image](https://github.com/iconara/awslogs-docker)

This is my service in my docker-compose.yml

```
  cloudwatch:
    image: iconara/awslogs:latest
    command: "--region eu-central-1 --config-file /etc/awslogs/app.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./environment/cloudwatch/conf/awscli.conf:/etc/awslogs/app.conf
      - ./environment/cloudwatch/state:/var/lib/awslogs/
      - ./logs:/app-logs/general/
      - ./project/storage/logs:/app-logs/laravel/
      - ~/.aws:/root/.aws
```

I am mounting the credentials so I can use this for development on Mac OSX which is probably not needed on an EC2 instance, depending on your setup.
I also mounted the state file so that the same logs wont be pushed twice if the container is restarted.

This is my `./environment/cloudwatch/conf/awscli.conf`

```
[general]
state_file = /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state
use_gzip_http_content_encoding = true

[/app-logs/logs/laravel.log]
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
file = /app-logs/laravel/laravel.log
buffer_duration = 5000
#log_stream_name = {instance_id}
log_stream_name = development
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = /app-logs/laravel/laravel.log
multi_line_start_pattern = {datetime_format}
```